# DataFrame frequency infos

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a mean to extract automatically the count of observation by hour ?

For exemple:
 - if the data are hourly, the result is 1
 - if the data are 30Min, the result is 2
 - if the data are 10Min, the result is 6, ...

Comment: Show some code, and some data. I think it should be something about `groupby()` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the frequency of your pandas index, if it has one then you just go

```
 df.index.freq
```

this will return you the frequency.

This might not be accurate depending on the series. What you have to do then is to take your column and index and "round" the dates to hours. Then you can count the unique values:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(df['timestamps'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'))
```

Average over all the counts and see the frequency per hour

Note that your problem is not as clear as you think. Timeseries can have "gaps", and there is always the question about the cutoff. So there is some ambiguity to your question. Only you can know the answer to what makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Which the following code, the need is to get 'H' (the frequency). Then, I can create a function to attribute 1 tfor'H', 2 for '30Min', ...

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 17520 entries, 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2016-12-30 23:00:00
Freq: H
Data columns (total 9 columns):
value            17520 non-null float64
```

I need to get the frequency parameter.

Comment: This is the question. I want to get only the frequency !

Comment: Please could you edit this into your question if it is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the following variable which do what I need :

```
>>> df.index.freqstr
'H'
```

Comment: df.index.freq is much much more usable! see my answer

Comment: Thank you Retozi, I didn't see your answer before but I have just marked it.